# Android getAbsolutePath(data.getData()) always returns null

Tags: java, android, io, uri

I am attempting to write an app to display the EXIF data for a user selected image (School's over and I'm bored)
While looking for how to allow the user to select the image, the general consensus online seems to be either, write your own file explorer, or use an intent to launch another app which can view files, and collect the data it returns.

I found the following code for this-`public class ListFileActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
ImageView imgView;
private String imgPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_file);

}

public void cameraClick(View view) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            setImageUri());
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}
public void galleryClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
            PICK_IMAGE);
}

public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
            String TAG = "Showing image";
            Log.v(TAG, "Showing the image with a path of " + selectedImagePath);
            //The path returns null, piece of crap

            //imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
        } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
            imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,
                    data);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
    // present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); //Was originally R.menu.main
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
        // 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}


}`
```

There are numerous different variations on this code, all of which are nearly the same, I found this one as it allows the camera to be used.

The problem is, that whichever code snippet I try, the directory returned is always null after selecting or taking an image. This happens both in the emulator and on my phone, across a variety of directories.

The app has the permissions needed-

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

As null is being returned, the cursor in getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) must be null, as this is when null is returned, but I don't understand why.

All help is appreciated

Edit- I have been adding some more log tags, and the cursor appears to be passing `if(cursor != null) {}`
It is `return cursor.getString(column_index)` which is returning null

Edit 2- The integer column_index, which is `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA)` returns 0

Answer (score 0):

try this method may help you

```
/**
 * @param contentURI
 * @return Return the selected ImagePath
 */
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = yourContext.getContentResolver().query(contentURI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using this method results in an idx value of -1, which also returns null when passed into cursor.getString(). Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Actually, something else in the code does work. contentURI.getPath() returns a path in the documents, not a full path as it begins /document/ but still something